# How to parse a string in c++

Tags: c++, string, parsing, char, cstring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I tokenize a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c)

So I am trying to parse a string and remove each individual word and store it into a char*.

Example:

```
string theString = "The quick brown fox.";
```

Turns into:

```
char* c1 = "The"
char* c2 = "quick"
char* c3 = "brown"
char* c4 = "fox."
```

I tried converting the string to a char* using c_str() but ran into compiling error saying: "invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*'.

Any ideas how to fix this then parse the converted cstring?

Comment: `char*` doesn't store anything but a memory address of the start of a character array in memory. Just saying.